# How can I send a GET request with json payload in the Robot Framework?

Tags: json, get, robotframework

I've looked at RESTinstance and RequestsLibrary, but can't find a way to send a GET to the server with JSON as part of my request. I am grateful for any advice.

Comment: Welcome. Please add our code and all relevant error messages and what you've tried to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Get Request keyword from the [RequestLibrary](http://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#Get%20Request) it could be done like below.
A JSON in general is a [dictionary](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dictionary-variable) in Robot Framework. In the example below the `&{JSON}` variable is equivalent with the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "peter",
  "other_attribute": "value"
}
```

With additional keywords you could create nested structures as well.

---

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           RequestsLibrary

*** Variables ***
&{JSON}    name=peter    other_attribute=value

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Create session    alias=my_session    url=http://127.0.0.1:5000
    ${response}=    Get Request    alias=my_session    uri=api/your_api_endpoint    json=${JSON}
    Log    ${response}
```